# Normal modes of cylinder and two pendulums

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

I am trying to understand(falsify) interpretation of the answer to the following problem:
 
[image]

Suppose we have cylinder of mass M which can oscillate along the horizontal line. There are two pendulums connected to the cylinder as shown in the image. This system has 3 normal frequencies. The first two are: 
$$0,\sqrt{\frac{g (M+2m)}{l M}}$$  Which one is the third one?

Proposed answer: $\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$ and **what interests me most** is interpretation of this answer:

Cylinder M stands still while two pendulums oscillate in opposite directions.

According to what I know when we consider certain normal mode **all degrees of freedom of the system are supposed to move with the same frequency**. Yet this seems to be in contradiction with aforementioned proposed answer. May be the correct interpretation is the following one:

- $0:$ all dofs move in the same direction(no oscillation)
- $\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}:$  both pendulums move in one direction while cylinder moves in the opposite one.
- $\sqrt{\frac{g (M+2m)}{l M}}:$ cylinder and one of the pendulums moves in one direction while second pendulum moves in the opposite direction.(I would suspect that this kind of oscillation is less likable hence should have higher frequency)

Which answer(if any) is the right one?

Comment: *Which answer (if any) is the right one?* You have only provided one answer, so there is no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answers are (in same order as yours)

- no oscillation (translation)
- the pendulums swing in antiphase, cylinder sits still
- the pendulums swing in phase, cylinder moves in antiphase

You are correct that, in a normal mode, all objects must move at the same frequency. However, I think you missed that an object that is not moving has an oscillation of zero amplitude and arbitrary frequency. Thus the cylinder can remain still during the motion.

It would also be worth considering how your proposed modes motion work.

For your proposal for the second mode, if the cylinder is moving, why would its relative mass to pendulums have no effect? Consider a very massive cylinder vs an almost massless one, wouldn't the massless one move more easily?

Your proposal for the third mode has more subtle problems, if you solve the equations of motion you will find that in will not stay in that mode and will evolve out of it over time, and then evolve back, since it is a combination of the true second and third modes. But perhaps seeing that intuitively takes a level of insight that need be developed through experience.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your answer. Now everything works for me.